# meta viewport content fixed width tag not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=600" />` into `_app.tsx` but is not working (chrome and mozilla). Seeing the html source in chrome dev tools it shows the tag applied tho.

This is how my `_app.tsx` file looks, `Head` tag is imported from 'next/head'

```
const spaceGrotesk = Space_Grotesk({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-space-grotesk',
});

const App = (props: AppPropsWithLayout): JSX.Element => {
  const {
    Component,
    pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
  } = props;
  const Layout = Component.Layout ?? NoLayout;

  return (
    <main className={${spaceGrotesk.variable} font-sans}>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=600" />
      </Head>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </main>
  );
};

export default trpc.withTRPC(App);
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-document-viewport-meta shows that the tag should go in `_app.tsx` but i tried putting the tag also in the `index.tsx` of the project and it replaces the one in `_app.tsx` but still nothing.